# how can I use a solve cvxopt in Julia?

Tags: julia, cvxopt, quadratic-programming

Hi I'm trying to use a solver cvxopt in Julia. So I made a code like this:

```
@time begin  
using PyCall  
using Pkg ENV["PYTHON"]=""        
Pkg.add("CVXOPT")  
Pkg.test("CVXOPT")  
using Compat.SparseArrays 
using NPZ

npzread("C:/Users/skqkr/Desktop/Semesterarbeit/Chiwan_Q1.npz") 
   Q = 2*(Matrix10["Q"]) 
   p = (Matrix10["p"])  
   G = (Matrix10["G"]) 
   h = (Matrix10["h"]) ## Rechte Seite von der Ungleichung
    
    sol = cvxopt.solvers.qp(Q, p, G, h, kktsolver="ldl", options=["kktreg":1e-9])
    
    print(sol) print(sol["x"])
    
        
         end  
end
```

it seems that everything is okay but after the Iterations come an Error like this.

```
    Certificate of dual infeasibility found.

     Testing CVXOPT tests passed 

UndefVarError: cvxopt not defined
```

How can I use a CVXOPT solver in Julia and what would be a problem in my code??

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`CVXOPT` is capitalized. Make sure to refer to it within the capitalized name as well (your code uses lowercase `cvxopt`):

```
@time begin  
using PyCall  
using Pkg ENV["PYTHON"]=""        
Pkg.add("CVXOPT")  
Pkg.test("CVXOPT")  
using Compat.SparseArrays 
using NPZ

npzread("C:/Users/skqkr/Desktop/Semesterarbeit/Chiwan_Q1.npz") 
   Q = 2*(Matrix10["Q"]) 
   p = (Matrix10["p"])  
   G = (Matrix10["G"]) 
   h = (Matrix10["h"]) ## Rechte Seite von der Ungleichung
    
    sol = CVXOPT.solvers.qp(Q, p, G, h, kktsolver="ldl", options=["kktreg":1e-9])
    
    print(sol) print(sol["x"])
    
        
         end  
end
```

(Tip: If the code is open source, look into their test folder to see how they call their library when you encounter problems. This will show how their library is conventionally called in a script.)